# How can I stream with gstreamer WebRTC protocol (webrtcsink-webrtcsrc-webrtcbin) between jetson nano and PC (gstreamer version 1.14.5)?

Tags: webrtc, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, gst-launch-1.0

I need an example to streaming with webrtcsink-webrtcsrc-webrtcbin using gst-launch-1.0 between
Jetson nano (gstreamer version 1.14.5) and PC (gstreamer version 1.20).

Give a pipeline that will send a h264 video stream between two devices (jetson - pc) and explain how can we use the protocol WebRTC with examples.